# Docker with wkhtmltopdf is not work correctly

Tags: php, docker, wkhtmltopdf, symphony-cms

I am trying to use wkhtmltopdf in a container with Docker and Symfony.
The installation is done well, but the result is very different from the reality, so I think some libraries must be missing in the system, but I don't know which one.

I've been checking other questions here and in google, but they don't help.

```
    FROM phpdockerio/php71-fpm:latest

    # Fix debconf warnings upon build
    ARG DEBIAN_FRONTEND=noninteractive

    # Install selected extensions and other stuff
    RUN apt-get update \
        && apt-get -y --no-install-recommends install  cron \
        php7.1-mysql \
        php-redis \
        php7.1-bcmath \ 
        php7.1-gd \
        php-imagick \
        php7.1-intl  \
        cron \
        python \
        xz-utils \
        libxrender1 \
        libfontconfig1 \
        zlib1g \ 
        fontconfig \ 
        libfreetype6 \ 
        libx11-6 \ 
        libxext6 \
        wkhtmltopdf

    RUN curl --insecure https://getcomposer.org/composer.phar -o /usr/bin/composer && chmod +x /usr/bin/composer


    RUN cd /tmp \
        && curl "https://downloads.wkhtmltopdf.org/0.12/0.12.4/wkhtmltox-0.12.4_linux-generic-amd64.tar.xz" -L -o "wkhtmltopdf.tar.xz" \
        && tar Jxvf wkhtmltopdf.tar.xz \
        && rm wkhtmltopdf.tar.xz \
        && mv wkhtmltox/include/* /usr/local/include/ \
        && mv wkhtmltox/lib/* /usr/local/lib/ \
        && mv wkhtmltox/bin/* /usr/local/bin/ \
        && mv wkhtmltox/share/* /usr/local/share/
RUN apt-get clean; rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/* /tmp/* /var/tmp/* /usr/share/doc/*

CMD php-fpm -F
```

This is the result in the container(docker)
[image]

And this is the result on my machine (without docker), as it should be.

[image]

Any idea what might be happening?